# Firebase database to facebook ads aduintid control

Tags: java, android-studio

i want to control facebook ad ids from firebase

```
public void loadBanner(){
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("adunits");
    rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            bannerId = String.valueOf(snapshot.child("banner").getValue().toString());
            }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });

    adView = new com.facebook.ads.AdView(this, bannerId, AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);

    // Find the Ad container
    LinearLayout adContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.banner_container);

    // Add the ad view to container
    adContainer.addView(adView);
 // Request an ad
    adView.loadAd();
}
```

Tihs is the code i am using the ads are not getting shown there is no error and app works properly

Comment: Check also whether banner id is coming from the Firebase database or not.

Answer (score 0):

Run the app again and check the Logcat you will get your device Hash ID. Put this hash ID in the below function.

```
AdSettings.addTestDevice("HASHED ID");
```

Use the above function before loading the ad in adview like this -

```
AdSettings.addTestDevice("HASHED ID");
adView.loadAd();
```